# Any interpretation for the fact that centroid = optimal point for maximising volume of such cuboid?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, centroid

(Visualising a sample case via the image at the bottom)

Consider a plane $\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc=1$ so that it intercepts with the axis at $(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$, $a,b,c >0$.  Now consider maximising the volume of such a cuboid, which it is in the first octant, with 3 faces in $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, and a vertex in the plane mentioned above.
Algebraically, we will always get the optimal vertex at the centroid of the triangle {$(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$} in the plane mentioned above.

Any possible interpretation behind this relation? I get the logic in algebra but I can’t figure out the intuition geometrically. The question sounds vague because I don’t have much intuition behind this relation so I fail to use specific words to phrase my question. It seems to be an interesting coincidence and I want to know is there any non-algebraic interpretation behind.

[image: 1]

blue line indicating the plane. Red line indicating the cuboid. Green indicating the vertex.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One thing you can note is that if you can handle the case $a=b=c=1$, which seems mentally easier, then you get all other cases by uniform stretching in one direction at a time. Uniform stretching of the triangle (multiplying all $x$ coordinates, say, by a factor $k$) also moves the centroid accordingly, and uniform stretching of any cuboid increases its volume accordingly $k$-fold, so the maximal cuboid stretches accordingly.

Comment: @Community: No, it is not at all hard to tell. The question is quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the simpler problem of finding the maximum volume of an inscribed cuboid (inscribed in the same manner as the original problem) in the first octant of the graph
$$x+y+z=1$$
By symmetry, one would intuitively hypothesize that this would occur when the green vertex of the cuboid was at the center of the triangular face and the cuboid was a cube. This can of course be proven with AM-GM ($xyz\leq \left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{27}$).

Since ratios of volumes are preserved under affine transformations, it follows that if we dilate the plane so that it matches with the equation $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$, then the maximum inscribed cube should be equivalent to applying that same affine transformation to the cube with sidelength $\frac{1}{3}$.

However, we also know that the location of the centroid will remain preserved after an affine transformation. Hence, it follows that this maximum-volume cube will also contain the centroid as a vertex regardless of the equation of the plane.